# JMeter-Problem with SSL certificate for url for 'XXXX'?Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert:certificate_unknown

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing

I am trying to record the flow of a native app whit Jmeter, but it is showing certificate error:

Example:
INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [42104]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'mdh-pa.googleapis.com' in map with key (mdh-pa.googleapis.com)

WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [42104]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'mdh-pa.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

The Jmeter.Property setting is defaul
I have also tried to change to:

https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2
https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

Answer (score -2):

The error indicates that you didn't configure your operating system and/or your application to use JMeter's MITM certificate.

The certificate is being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you launch [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and you need to install the file onto your device.

The instructions differ depending on the operating system, refer to your OS vendor documentation for more details or include OS information including version into your question.

Reference steps:

- [Trust manually installed certificate profiles in iOS and iPadOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)
- [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)
- [Install a Self-Signed Certificate on a Windows Computer](https://pubs.vmware.com/flex-11/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.horizon.flex.admin.doc%2FGUID-4F29CCE6-2F04-461D-81EF-C1480B1A8E84.html)