# Problem with SSL certificate for url for 'XXXX'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing

I am trying to record a flow in Jmeter, but its showing below error :

Jmeter - 5.6.3

Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'XXXX'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host terminated the handshake

I have generated the Jmeter cert and also imported it to the firefox browser, few requests are getting recorded and on others, getting above error.

I found a question already raised but it is slightly different from mine and also the solution given there does not work for me -  *[JMeter-Problem with SSL certificate for url for 'XXXX'?Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert:certificate_unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292748/jmeter-problem-with-ssl-certificate-for-url-for-xxxxensure-browser-is-set-to?rq=2)*

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you generate a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate you're supplying a hostname or IP address of the system under test you're trying to record.

I guess the requests targeting the system under test are recorded properly.

But requests to 3rd-party services like [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), fonts, whatever are not being recorded.

First of all you should neither record nor replay them as if they're 3rd-party you don't have any control over them and running these requests won't make any sense.

If some requests to the system under test domain(s) cannot be recorded due to the SSL problem it might be due to browser built-in security mechanisms like [certificate pinning](https://www.ssl.com/blogs/what-is-certificate-pinning/), for example you visited the system under test without JMeter's proxy and browser "remembers" the certificate chain and when you're trying to access the system under test via proxy it detects mismatch and terminates the connection. In this case you need to [clear your browsing history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox).

Alternatively you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeter-chrome-plugin), it's less "invasive" and you don't need to worry about proxies and certificates.